# Trying to run Mutillidae

Tags: php

I get this message in my browser when trying to run Mutillidae

> "Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp\htdocs\mutillidae\owasp-esapi-php\lib\apache-log4php\trunk\src\main\php\helpers\LoggerPatternParser.php on line 114"

I have down loaded xampp and I can get to http://localhost/phpmyadmin/. But when trying to get to http://127.0.0.1/mutillidae/, the Fatal error message comes up and don't know what to do. I am a noob at this so bear with me. Can anyone tell me how to fix this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158548/array-and-string-offset-access-syntax-with-curly-braces-is-deprecated pls refer this

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)