# Dynamic method name in PHP8

Tags: php

In a loop I want a trait to populate the member variables.

**Problem:**

My IDE tells me:

> Array and String Offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer
> supported.

**My code**

```
use CustomTrait;

private function mapUserData($mapping, $userData){

  foreach($mapping as $owerKey => $theirKey) {
       $this->set{$owerKey} = $userData[$theirKey];
  }
}
```

Comment: Better to mention PHP version as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59158548/array-and-string-offset-access-syntax-with-curly-braces-is-deprecated)

Comment: @ImranZahoor you right! i updated the title with version.

Answer (score 3):

If you want a [dynamic method](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php), you probably want this:

```
$this->{"set$owerKey"}($userData[$theirKey])
```

The syntax you're using is for an entirely [different purpose](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr):

```
$foo = 'Hello, World!';
var_dump($foo{0});
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/ZhVjS)

Answer (score 2):

Try =)

```
<?php 

class Test
{
    use CustomTrait;

    private function mapUserData($mapping, $userData): void
    {
        foreach ($mapping as $owerKey => $theirKey) {
            $methodName = "set{$owerKey}";

            // check method
            if (!\method_exists($this, $methodName)) {
                continue;
            }

            $this->{$methodName}($userData[$theirKey]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Forgot to response. Thank you Oleh for the answear!