# Joomla Update Causing Frontend and Backend Issues – Admin Panel 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, .htaccess, joomla, joomla-extensions

**Frontend Issue: Fox Contact Extension Compatibility**

I recently updated a really old Joomla website from version 3.3 to version 3.10 to ensure compatibility with PHP 7. While the update was successful, I encountered an issue with the contact page due to the "Fox Contact" extension becoming obsolete. After the Joomla update, the contact page stopped displaying correctly showing me this error:
[image]

Is anyone else facing a similar issue with outdated extensions after updating Joomla? Any recommendations on how to address this specific issue or suggestions for alternative contact form extensions compatible with Joomla 3.10 would be greatly appreciated.

**Backend Issue: Admin Panel 500 Internal Error and .htaccess**

Additionally, the admin panel was showing a "500 Internal Server Error." Upon investigation, I discovered that the issue is related to the .htaccess file. When I renamed it, the admin panel displayed normally. However, not all the pages were accessible I couldn't edit articles or categories unless I switch back to php version 5.6. Here's the error showing in the admin page:
[image]
and here's the htaccess file in administrator:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "administrator"
AuthUserFile "/home/africamultiple/.htpasswds/public_html/melico/administrator/passwd"
require valid-user
```

Are there specific changes that need to be made to the .htaccess file to resolve this issue? I really have to update php version as everything in the website is deprecated.

Any insights, suggestions, or troubleshooting steps to resolve these frontend and backend issues would be immensely helpful. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Comment: If the .htaccess really contains only those directives, then most likely the `AuthUserFile` can't actually be found under the specified path. Go check what the server error log has to say.

Comment: I checked error logs from Cpanel this is what I found: [Wed Jan 24 04:04:06.411561 2024] [core:crit] [pid 3595851:tid 23164695906048] (13)Permission denied: [client 116.203.28.43:0] AH00529: /home/roch4634/africamultiple.com/melico/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/home/roch4634/africamultiple.com/melico/' is executable, referer: http://africamultiple.com/

Comment: So, go and make sure the .htaccess file is readable for the current web server user, and that the directory has the "executable" bit set.

Comment: The directory permission is set to 0755 and for the htaccess file is 0644

Comment: You were talking about the .htaccess file in your admin folder first, but the paths in the error message you quoted, are not inside your `administrator` folder.

Comment: Yes, but the front-end works fine now after updating, the problem is in admin, I added this code to index.php: "ini_set('display_errors','On'); 
error_reporting(E_ALL); " so I can see the error, when I try and create a new article it shows me this error: Deprecated: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is deprecated in /home/roch4634/melico.dz/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/classes/utility.php on line 238

Fatal error: Switch statements may only contain one default clause in /home/roch4634/melico.dz/components/com_jce/editor/libraries/classes/document.php on line 279

Comment: For the first one, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/59158548/1427878 And the second should be self-explanatory. What's _not_ clear though, is whyyou should even get any such errors in the first place, _if_ the code was actually compatible with the used PHP version, because apparently it _isn't_.

Answer (score 0):

The function name must be a string error generally happens the following way:

- You have function called myJoomlaFunction();
- You call it the following way: $myJoomlaFunction();

Notice the $ at the beginning.

It might be that an avalanche of errors has led to this error. When this happens, the most practical method to debug would be to disable 3rd party extensions one by one, and changing the template to a default one. Of course, enabling debug in Joomla should help, as well as setting the error reporting to the "maximum".